# Crontab with SVN and Git

Tags: ssh, cron, git, github

I have some repos which are both in SVN and Git. My username is guyfawkes, and in my home directory I have folder www which contains all my repos. In this directory I also have file update.sh:

```
[guyfawkes@guyfawkes-desktop ~/www]$ cat update.sh
cd /home/guyfawkes/www
cd crm
echo "upd crm"
svn up
echo "update crm completed"
echo "-------"
cd ../crm_sql
echo "upd sql"
svn up
echo "update sql completed"
echo "-------"
cd ../crm_old
echo "upd old"
svn up
echo "update old completed"
echo "-------"
cd ../mysqldiff
echo "upd mysqldiff"
git pull sotmarket master
echo "update mysqlidff completed"
git push origin master
echo "push to github completed"
echo "-------"
cd ../mysql-migration-manager
echo "upd mmmm"
git pull
echo "mmm updated"
cd data
echo "upd data"
git pull
echo "data updated"
```

My crontab is:

```
[guyfawkes@guyfawkes-desktop ~/www]$ crontab -l
*/5 * * * * /home/guyfawkes/www/update.sh
```

So, it works perfectly with svn repos, but I have this mails in /var/spool/mail/guyfawkes (from cron):

```
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/guyfawkes>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=guyfawkes>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=guyfawkes>

upd crm

Fetching external item into 'public/old'
External at revision 32674.

At revision 483.
update crm completed
-------
upd sql
At revision 29.
update sql completed
-------
upd old
At revision 32674.
update old completed
-------
upd mysqldiff
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
update mysqlidff completed
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
push to github completed
-------
upd mmmm
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
mmm updated
upd data
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
data updated
```

How can I to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to update from github which requires an ssh
key. Either create a dedicated ssh key without a password on your server
and add it to your github account or use the http-readonly uri to update
your repository:

```
git pull --mirror https://github.com/account/repository.git
```

Comment: How can I to create this key?